# Weird geometry on Bevel tool

Tags: bevel

I'm working on my knife model and I want to add more smooth edges on the grip. When i use bevel tool i get weird geometry, because of angles on my model.

[image]
[image]

How can I make my edges smooth just the grip?

[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file so that we can try: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi. File added. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to delete the (inner) faces that are on the mirror axis. Don't you want to use Subdivision Surface? If you use it it works fine, you can then sharpen the blade with additional edge loops if necessary

Comment: That's good idea. I knew that I can add this modifier, but don't know why I wanted t make this with bevel. Thanks